# Is the cx2072x codec added to the Linux kernel 4.18?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, audio, laptop

I am using an E200HA laptop and I am having a problem with the CX2072X codec. Has this problem been fixed in the Linux kernel 4.18?
If not, do you have any developers who participated in the official merger?

- Google translator is used for English translation

Comment: Why don't check yourself? https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/?h=v4.18.11

Comment: @IporSircer thank you for telling me! I am still learning.

Comment: Googling finds [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1021347), and the [git repository](https://github.com/heikomat/linux) works for 4.16, so even if there is no "official merger", it should be possible to port it with a bit of effort to 4.18 (just merge changes from the official upstream, chances for conflicts are low). Usings diffs, you should also be able to see if someone has "officially" done something about it in 4.18. (Yes, you'll need to read up about using git, and compiling your kernel).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn’t been merged (yet); it’s only available in [Takashi Iwai’s sound tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/), but only for 4.13 (look at [the list of topic branches](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/refs/heads)). You’ll be able to see when it’s merged by looking for the appearance of `sound/soc/codecs/cx2072x.c` in the kernel source.

The driver can be forward-ported to current kernels, as shown in [Heiko Mathes’ fork of 4.16 and 4.19](https://github.com/heikomat/linux) (in the [`cx2072x`](https://github.com/heikomat/linux/tree/cx2072x) and [`cx2072x_4.19`](https://github.com/heikomat/linux/tree/cx2072x_4.19) branches respectively). See also [How to build the driver for cx2072x codec](https://askubuntu.com/q/1001071/412264).

Comment: I'm still maintaining the fork. the cx2072x-branch is up to date with linux 4.18, and i just merged 4.19-rc7 into a new branch cx2072x_4.19

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @Neutrosider, I’ve updated the info in the answer accordingly.